# Pandas transposition inside dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have this datasate now:

```
animal   age             count
dogs     1               49
         2              134
         3              147
         4              154
cats     1              189
         2              254
         3              259
         4              261
```

I would like to convert age column to 4 age columns for each age:

```
animal   age1 age2 age3 age4 
dogs      49   134  147  154  
cats     ....................
```

I have tried df.T and df.transpose() but both of them return my original column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [pd.pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
In [25]: result = df.pivot(index='animal', columns='age', values='count')

In [26]: result
Out[26]: 
age       1    2    3    4
animal                    
cats    189  254  259  261
dogs     49  134  147  154

In [27]: result.columns = ['age{:d}'.format(col) for col in result.columns]

In [28]: result
Out[28]: 
        age1  age2  age3  age4
animal                        
cats     189   254   259   261
dogs      49   134   147   154
```