# rotating data in pandas MultiIndex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a MultiIndex dataframe looks like, this is only partial. The Year range frome 2007 to 2015 with the same places for each year.

```
                Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May  June  July   Aug  Sept   Oct  \
Year Place                                                                     
2007 Johore       1.26  1.07  1.21  1.27  1.33  1.28  1.67  1.88  1.89  1.86   
     Kedah        1.20  1.27  1.50  1.38  1.38  1.52  1.84  2.09  2.08  2.02   
     Kelantan     0.92  0.90  1.01  1.10  1.07  0.87  0.93  1.02  1.08  1.17   
     Malacca      1.62  1.45  1.64  1.52  1.50  1.40  1.75  1.80  2.03  2.14   
     N. Sembilan  0.98  0.94  1.11  1.07  1.10  1.16  1.46  1.58  1.61  1.71   

                   Nov   Dec  
Year Place                    
2007 Johore       1.95  1.72  
     Kedah        1.79  1.39  
     Kelantan     1.29  0.97  
     Malacca      2.44  2.13  
     N. Sembilan  1.75  1.58
```

I want to rotate the data and  get a single index dataframe with the index being months (e.g. 2007-Jan,2007-Feb ) and the columns being different places.

I tried 'Pahang' as an example and did:

```
In [14]:

Pahang=df.xs('Pahang',level='Place')
In [15]:

Pahang.unstack().unstack().unstack()
Out[15]:
Year      
2007  Jan     1.19
      Feb     1.01
      Mar     1.13
      Apr     1.19
      May     1.24
      June    1.17
      July    1.43
      Aug     1.59
      Sept    1.63
      Oct     1.64
      Nov     1.82
      Dec     1.31
2008  Jan     1.57
      Feb     1.36
      Mar     1.56
...
2014  Oct     1.87
      Nov     1.74
      Dec     1.09
2015  Jan     0.93
      Feb     1.02
      Mar     1.28
      Apr     1.51
      May      NaN
      June     NaN
      July     NaN
      Aug      NaN
      Sept     NaN
      Oct      NaN
      Nov      NaN
      Dec      NaN
Length: 108, dtype: float64
```

I get the Pahang column as I want. Instead of doing it one place at a time, I am wondering if there is a way to loop through all places in a faster way.
Thanks!

Comment: Following your last post, you are doing great on formatting the post. :-) To make it even better, it's always a good practice to include a reproducible example. This could be either a code snippet to simulate some artificial data that has the same structure as your real dataset, or upload the `csv` string by `df.to_csv()` so that others can quickly reproduce your dataset in a minimum effort. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can do the reshaping for all `Places` and then select just one of them.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# your data
# ===================================
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([np.arange(2007,2016,1), 'A B C D E'.split()], names=['Year', 'Place'])
df = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(45,12), columns='Jan Feb Mar Apr May June July Aug Sept Oct Nov Dec'.split(), index=multi_index)

df


               Jan     Feb     Mar   ...       Oct     Nov     Dec
Year Place                           ...                          
2007 A     -0.1512  0.7274 -0.3218   ...    1.2547 -1.8408  1.2585
     B      0.0856 -1.0458 -1.1428   ...    1.0194  1.1958  0.4905
     C     -1.2021 -0.6989 -0.0486   ...   -0.8053 -0.4929  1.6475
     D     -1.9948 -0.3465  1.3036   ...   -0.2490  0.6285 -0.0568
     E      0.0928 -1.3905  0.7203   ...   -0.1138  2.9552 -0.0272
2008 A     -1.2595  1.3072  0.6121   ...   -1.4275  0.8769  2.0671
     B      0.3611 -0.4187 -2.9609   ...   -1.2944  1.2752 -0.0947
     C      1.6492  0.0340 -0.9743   ...    0.0550  1.4135  0.8862
     D      0.9034 -0.2957  0.2152   ...    1.0947 -0.2405  0.0367
     E      0.9566  1.1927  0.0852   ...    0.7396  0.8240 -1.6628
...            ...     ...     ...   ...       ...     ...     ...
2014 A      0.7478 -0.8905  0.6238   ...   -1.0907 -0.2919  0.3261
     B      3.6764 -0.0601  1.2751   ...    0.3294 -1.3375 -1.5087
     C      2.3460 -0.4181  0.0607   ...   -0.8270  0.0536 -0.4353
     D      0.9733 -0.6863  0.5278   ...   -1.8206  0.4788  1.1438
     E     -0.3514  2.4570 -0.8567   ...    1.3434 -1.5634 -0.9984
2015 A      1.2849 -1.0657 -0.1173   ...   -0.1733  0.0441  0.0922
     B      0.5802 -0.5912  1.1193   ...   -0.1296 -0.6374 -1.7727
     C     -0.5026 -1.3111 -0.5499   ...    0.7308  1.2570  0.8733
     D     -1.6482 -0.2213  0.3336   ...   -1.3141 -2.0377 -1.1468
     E     -2.0796 -0.2808 -1.4079   ...   -0.3052  0.7999  0.3516

[45 rows x 12 columns]

# processing
# ==================================
res = df.stack().unstack(level='Place')

Place           A       B       C       D       E
Year                                             
2007 Jan  -0.1512  0.0856 -1.2021 -1.9948  0.0928
     Feb   0.7274 -1.0458 -0.6989 -0.3465 -1.3905
     Mar  -0.3218 -1.1428 -0.0486  1.3036  0.7203
     Apr  -1.4641  2.0384  0.6518  0.8756 -1.4627
     May  -0.8896 -1.6627  0.6990  0.2008  0.7423
     June -0.5339 -0.6629  0.1121  0.3618  1.3838
     July -0.4851  0.6544  0.5251  0.3394 -0.7016
     Aug  -1.2445  0.9671 -1.0684 -0.4776 -0.2936
     Sept  1.1330 -0.7543  1.6029  0.5543  0.3234
     Oct   1.2547  1.0194 -0.8053 -0.2490 -0.1138
...           ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2015 Mar  -0.1173  1.1193 -0.5499  0.3336 -1.4079
     Apr  -1.0528  0.2421  0.3419 -2.1137 -0.2836
     May  -1.0709 -0.1794 -0.2682 -0.3226  0.8654
     June -1.4538 -0.7313  0.3177 -1.4008  1.1357
     July -1.6210 -0.3815 -0.9876  0.1019  1.7450
     Aug   0.5692  0.7679  1.1893 -0.9612  0.0903
     Sept  0.2371  0.6740  0.9204 -0.2909 -0.8197
     Oct  -0.1733 -0.1296  0.7308 -1.3141 -0.3052
     Nov   0.0441 -0.6374  1.2570 -2.0377  0.7999
     Dec   0.0922 -1.7727  0.8733 -1.1468  0.3516

[108 rows x 5 columns]


# select one place
res['A']

Year      
2007  Jan    -0.1512
      Feb     0.7274
      Mar    -0.3218
      Apr    -1.4641
      May    -0.8896
      June   -0.5339
      July   -0.4851
      Aug    -1.2445
      Sept    1.1330
      Oct     1.2547
               ...  
2015  Mar    -0.1173
      Apr    -1.0528
      May    -1.0709
      June   -1.4538
      July   -1.6210
      Aug     0.5692
      Sept    0.2371
      Oct    -0.1733
      Nov     0.0441
      Dec     0.0922
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `unstack` to swap index levels, you could use [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.swaplevel.html):

```
In [157]: df.xs('Johore',level='Place').unstack().swaplevel(0,1)
Out[157]: 
Year      
2007  Jan     1.26
      Feb     1.07
      Mar     1.21
      Apr     1.27
      May     1.33
      June    1.28
      July    1.67
      Aug     1.88
      Sept    1.89
      Oct     1.86
dtype: float64
```

There is also the [`reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reorder_levels.html) method which can be useful if your MultiIndex has many levels and need to perform more than one swap.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking roughly along the same lines as @HappyLeapSecond, but will add this because it's not quite the same and is a little more general (for all rows rather than just a particular one).

First off, I'm going to use a slightly different sample dataset.  Note also that I'm posting without the multi-index because a single level index is easier to copy and paste into pandas.

```
   year     place   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May  June  July   Aug
0  2007    Johore  1.26  1.07  1.21  1.27  1.33  1.28  1.67  1.88
1  2007     Kedah  1.20  1.27  1.50  1.38  1.38  1.52  1.84  2.09
2  2007  Kelantan  0.92  0.90  1.01  1.10  1.07  0.87  0.93  1.02
3  2007   Malacca  1.62  1.45  1.64  1.52  1.50  1.40  1.75  1.80
4  2008    Johore  1.26  1.07  1.21  1.27  1.33  1.28  1.67  1.88
5  2008     Kedah  1.20  1.27  1.50  1.38  1.38  1.52  1.84  2.09
6  2008  Kelantan  0.92  0.90  1.01  1.10  1.07  0.87  0.93  1.02
7  2008   Malacca  1.62  1.45  1.64  1.52  1.50  1.40  1.75  1.80
```

Then, set the index so it's comparable to the one in the question:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).set_index(['year','place'])

                Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May  June  July   Aug
year place                                                   
2007 Johore    1.26  1.07  1.21  1.27  1.33  1.28  1.67  1.88
     Kedah     1.20  1.27  1.50  1.38  1.38  1.52  1.84  2.09
     Kelantan  0.92  0.90  1.01  1.10  1.07  0.87  0.93  1.02
     Malacca   1.62  1.45  1.64  1.52  1.50  1.40  1.75  1.80
2008 Johore    1.26  1.07  1.21  1.27  1.33  1.28  1.67  1.88
     Kedah     1.20  1.27  1.50  1.38  1.38  1.52  1.84  2.09
     Kelantan  0.92  0.90  1.01  1.10  1.07  0.87  0.93  1.02
     Malacca   1.62  1.45  1.64  1.52  1.50  1.40  1.75  1.80
```

And then some switching around, resorting, etc.  The main "problem" you have in your data is that you start with the year in the row axis but the month in the column axis.  So what you need to do is move the year indexing from the row to the column.  That's done with `unstack(level='year')`.  The rest of it is basically just a matter of cleaning up.

```
df.unstack(level='year').swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).T.sortlevel(0)

place      Johore  Kedah  Kelantan  Malacca
year                                       
2007 Jan     1.26   1.20      0.92     1.62
     Feb     1.07   1.27      0.90     1.45
     Mar     1.21   1.50      1.01     1.64
     Apr     1.27   1.38      1.10     1.52
     May     1.33   1.38      1.07     1.50
     June    1.28   1.52      0.87     1.40
     July    1.67   1.84      0.93     1.75
     Aug     1.88   2.09      1.02     1.80
2008 Jan     1.26   1.20      0.92     1.62
     Feb     1.07   1.27      0.90     1.45
     Mar     1.21   1.50      1.01     1.64
     Apr     1.27   1.38      1.10     1.52
     May     1.33   1.38      1.07     1.50
     June    1.28   1.52      0.87     1.40
     July    1.67   1.84      0.93     1.75
     Aug     1.88   2.09      1.02     1.80
```

**Edit to add:**  This last line can be simplified by using @JianxunLi's solution.

```
df.stack().unstack(level='place')
```

That's a better way of solving the problem of getting year/month on the same index and place on the opposite index, but I'll leave this answer here for now in the event that seeing an alternate method and explanation is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pandas.pivot`.
An example is here:
[Pandas transposition inside dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116600/pandas-transposition-inside-dataframe)

Comment: This answer is a little sparse on the details, but pivot or pivot_table would be another good way to approach the problem.